# R Automatically cut specific decimal when a vector is called under condition

Tags: r

I'm a poor lookie R user.

I created 2 vectors

```
x <- seq(0,30, 0.1)
y <- dchisq(x, df = 11)
```

and the 'y' vector has ten-trillionth decimal point values 
like '0.00057293674316'

But if it were called like

```
y[which(x>=17.3)]
```

it has billionth decimal point values
like '0.0005729367'

i don't want to lose rest of decimal values.

How can I solve this?

Thank you~

Comment: Try with `print` i.e. `print(y[which(x>=17.3)], digits = 16)`

Comment: If you want to make the above suggestion by akrun permanent, use `options(digits=16)`.

Comment: Wow..simple solution..Thank you!